# Using jQuery autosuggest plugin, how can I generating multiple checkboxes for the cities

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm not really good at Javascript/jQuery yet, so I need some help.
I have a [jQuery autosuggest plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) on my site, where users can select multiple cities, from my database. What I want now, is to generate a checkbox for every city they selected.
So, let's say users slects cities with id's 23, 634, 78 and 254, it would generate this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="23" name="city[]" /> City 1
<input type="checkbox" value="634" name="city[]" /> City 2
<input type="checkbox" value="78" name="city[]" /> City 3
<input type="checkbox" value="254" name="city[]" /> City 4
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the user selects a city from the autosuggest widget, you can use this code to add a checkbox to an element named 'parent':

```
$('#parent').append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + cityId + '" name="city[]" /> ' + cityName);
```

Assuming the city's id is held in the variable cityId and the name in cityName.

Comment: Actually, there is no variable for city id nor city name. The plugin does however generate this: `<li class="as-selection-item" id="as-selection-1">
        <a class="as-close">×</a>Velenje</li>
    <li class="as-original" id="as-original-1">
        <input type="hidden" class="as-values" name="as_values_1" id="as-values-1" value="681,">`, Velenje being City name and 681 being city ID.

Comment: You'll need to extract the relevant information from the data returned by the plugin. If you don't know how to do that, I'd suggest asking another question or at least updating this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tm='<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" />';

var arr= [23,5,6,7];

$.each (arr,function (i,n) {
alert(n);
$('body').append($(tm).val(n));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cities = [23, 42, 73],
    cityNames = {
      23: "Conspiracy Ville",
      42: "Meaning of Life City",
      73: "Best Number of All Town"
    };

$(cities).each(function (index,cityID) {
  $('body')
    .append(
      '<input value="'+cityID+'" type="checkbox" name="city[]" /> '
        + cityNames[cityID] 
        + '<br>'
  );
});
```

See a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nils_r/KaJBD/